# Identify Windows Process Page Fault cause

Tags: memory-management, paging, page-fault

On `Windows` I use a commercial software that to perform a certain task can run even for 18 hours.

By inspecting the task manager the process reports a huge amount  of page faults, something like 65M page faults and a memory usage peak aroung 1GB.

The machine has 2 GB ram and 2 GB of virtual memory, and a paging file ranging between 2 and 4 GB.

To reduce the execution time I'm thinking to reduce the effects of page faults by using a tool like [ramdisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) to store most accessed files. But to understand which those files are I need to discover wich are the memory accesses producing the page faults. Is there any way/tool to accomplish this task? Does anybody see an alternative to this approach?

Comment: Check out here for a better understanding of page faults: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684365/what-causes-page-faults

Comment: Page faults are caused by processes which consume more memory than physically available. To reduce the number of page faults, either memory has to be increased or the memory usage reduced. By installing a ramdisk, you basically reduce the memory available to your application. Use the task manager to identify superfluous processes which you could stop to free some memory.